# Datasnapshot's getValue() method is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been struggling with this issue for about three days. Or may be I am not understanding the who concept of `addValueEventListener()`. I have a POJO class.

```
public class InstantMessage {

    private String UID;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String type;

    public InstantMessage() {
    }

    public InstantMessage(String newUID, String newEmail, String newPassword, String newType) {
        UID = newUID;
        email = newEmail;
        password = newPassword;
        type = newType;
    }

    public void setUID(String newUID) {
        UID = UID;
    }

    public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
        email = newEmail;
    }

    public void setPassword(String newPassword) {
        password = newPassword;
    }

    public void setType(String newType) {
        type = newType;
    }

    public String getUID() {
        return UID;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is to fetch "type" node from Firebase database. My database reference is:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

I have tried to loop through the Datasnapshot object still no luck.

Here's what I am trying to do.

```
private void showData(){

        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                InstantMessage iM1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
                //System.out.println("The type is:" + iM1.getType());
                sampleUser.add(iM1);
                studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

As you can see in the logs that Datasnapshot is getting an object I am looking for but values are null.

[image]

[image]

I am so sorry if it's just a novice question but I am trying hard to learn it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a list of all users (from `/Users`), and then try to map the entire result to a single `InstantMessage`. That won't work, since the properties in `InstantMessage` don't exist straight in `/Users`, they are one level deeper in your JSON.

To solve this problem, you'll need to loop over the child nodes of your snapshot to get at the individual messages:

```
mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            InstantMessage iM1 = messageSnapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
            sampleUser.add(iM1);
        }
        studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you s much Frank. You're a life saver.